# Why only the first "rake" command is executed in a batch file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, batch-file, rake

I created `reset_db.bat` on Windows with the following content:

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

When I type `reset_db` only the first command (`drop`) is executed. Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the rake is also a .bat file.

Then you only have to prepend it with a call

```
call rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development
call rake db:create
call rake db:migrate
call rake db:seed
```